# Save auxiliary Latex files in another folder in VSC

Tags: auxiliary-files, visual-studio-code

I have started to configure VSC as my default latex text editor, using the **"Latex Workshop"** extension.

My question is: How can I make the auxiliary files generated when compiling the project be saved in a separate folder? files (.aux, .bbl, .blg, .fls ...)

I read that this can be done by adding **--aux-directory=FOLDER** to the compile-time statement but I don't know how I can do that in VSC.

Any idea how to do it?

Thank you very much.

Comment: I would not do it unless you know very well how all the tools (bibtex, biber, makeindex, etc) have to be configured to find their input files in the auxiliary folder. It is much less trouble to let the files in the folder where the tex programs are expecting them by default.

Comment: Yes, but I read that by specifying the directory for the auxiliary files with that command, the compiler knows where they are when it needs them

Comment: Pdflatex would know but not the other tools or scripts.

Comment: Is there a specific problem that motivates this need for another folder ?

Answer (score 6):

If you are using pdflatex, you can add the flag `--aux-directory=.aux` to the tool arguments in the setting.json file, such as:

```json
{
    "name": "pdflatex",
    "command": "pdflatex",
    "args": [
        "-synctex=1",
        "-interaction=nonstopmode",
        "-file-line-error",
        "--aux-directory=.aux",
        "%DOC%"
    ],
    "env": {}
},
```

The synctex file will still be in the source directory. You need it there next to the pdf.

Then it is convenient to just add the .aux folder to .gitignore if you are using it.

Comment: Where do you access `settings.json`?

Comment: @PaulWintz Bit late to it, but for anyone looking for this in the future, it's Cmd/Ctrl + Shift + P (Command Palette) > Preferences: Open Workspace Settings (JSON)

Comment: @PaulWintz create a `.vscode` folder in your project directory. then create a `settings.json` there. Visual Studio Code will automatically load every time you invoke/open it from within that folder.

Comment: this is not the correct answer. `pdflatex` has the option `-output-directory=<path>`

Answer (score 5):

A very simple solution is to save everything in a temporary folder. This is easy to set up: Search for "latex outdir" in settings, and set it to `%TMPDIR%` as in the image below.

This will also write the pdf into a temporary folder, which I personally like. If you want to check the pdf, just use Ctrl+Alt+V. You may then optionally save the pdf from the viewer.

[image]

Comment: what's Ctrl+Alt+V on mac? where can I see this defined?

Comment: In MacOS it should be Command+Alt+V. You can find it by opening the Command+Shift+P prompt and typing "preview pdf". The command for previewing the pdf should be listed in the options with it's respective shortcut.

Comment: I have to say the short-cut might be conflict with other software (like mine, it was occupied by Evernote), the unambiguous ways is type "LaTex Workshop View LaTex PDF file" after open the `Ctrl + Alt + P` or `Command + Shift + P`, or just resolve the conflict, :)

Answer (score 3):

**Step One**: On vscode, open the Preferences (UI)

[image]

**Step Two**: search for `latex OutDir`

[image]

**Step Three**: in the field `Latex-workshop Latex: Out Dir`, update the input to `%DIR%/<insert-path>` where `<insert-path>` is the path where you want the output to be placed.

[image]

Note: This solution is relevant for vsCode and the extension '[Latex Workshop](https://github.com/James-Yu/LaTeX-Workshop)'.

Answer (score 2):

I have specifically created a python module for saving the auxiliary files that are generated by LaTeX and BibTeX engines into a desired folder. On my GitHub site are more informations: https://github.com/amrane99/LaTeXCompiler. The compilation of the file will then be executed using a single command in the Terminal. Once the module has been installed (using pip) you can simply compile the .tex file using lualatex and no BibTeX engine eg. as follows *-- the generated files will be stored in the .aux_files folder --*:

```
LaTeXCompiler -file <full_path_to_file>.tex 
              -tex_engine lualatex -no_bib_engine -aux_folder .aux_files
```