# How to force VSCode to seach for sty files in a folder called TeXAuX

Tags: packages, vscode

Is there a way to "force" Visual Studio Code (VSCode) to search for sty files in a folder called TeXAuX?

I saw a post [found here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/525604/save-auxiliary-latex-files-in-another-folder-in-vsc) that tells VSCode to save the aux files etc. in another folder. I do not know how to configure VSCode to search in that specific folder.

Any help will be sincerely appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: It's LaTeX (or pdflatex or xelatex) itself you would need to configure to do that, not your editor like VS Code. What TeX distribution are you using, and on what platform?

Comment: VSCode doesn't do searching for `.sty` files (if you mean searching so that they can be used in your document). This is done by the TeX distribution. So the proper place to put files is either in the root folder of your document, or in your local `texmf` folder (in which case they can be used by any document).

Comment: @frabjous, I am using MiKTeX on Windows 10

Comment: @AlanMunn, can you specify a folder then in the root folder for the `.sty` files?

Comment: I don't use MikTeX myself, but does this [question here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30087/how-do-i-set-the-search-path-for-miktex) help? It's a bit of an older post, so I hope the same steps still apply.

Comment: There's also slightly different instructions [here (under Registering a user-managed TEXMF root directory)](https://miktex.org/howto/miktex-console); since I don't have MikTeX myself, and don't know what version you've got, I can't check, but it'll be something like that.

Comment: I don't use MikTeX either, but setting a different subfolder for each document seems more trouble than it's worth. Is there a reason why you don't want to use a local `texmf` folder instead?

Comment: @AlanMunn, I use different `.sty` files at times and continually modify them.  I just thought keeping the `.sty` files with the working document folder is easier.

Comment: You can keep the .sty file in the same folder as the .tex file without doing any extra configuration, but keeping it in a special subfolder of that folder is more work.